# Need for help in this scrapy regular expression

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am pretty new to scrapy, I am trying to crawl a website using CrawlSpider, I want to crawl it recursively based on the "Next" button. But it is not working. I think the problem comes from the regular expression, but I checked for so many times, I can not find mistake. It only crawl the landing page without proceed to the next page.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

start_urls = ['https://shopping.yahoo.com/merchantrating/?mid=13652']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "/merchantrating/;_ylt=Anf3hF19R8MGFPwuYuJUny4cEb0F\?mid=13652&sort=1&start=\d+"), callback = 'parse_start_url', follow = True),
)

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    contents = sel.xpath('//p')
    for content in contents:
        item = BedbugsItem()
        item['pageContent'] = content.xpath('text()').extract()
        self.items.append(item)
    return self.items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a XPath instead:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        restrict_xpaths = [
            "//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(., 'Next')]"
        ]),
    callback = 'parse_start_url',
    follow = True),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but can you tell me why my solution is not working properly?

Comment: @PoppinDouble I think it's that ``;_ylt=Anf3hF19R8MGFPwuYuJUny4cEb0F`` bit -- looks like some tracking thing that works only in the browser.